# Global Variable in plsql

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, plsql-package

I have created one package.

In the package specification I declared one variable `l_emp_name varchar2(100);` which I am using in the package body in various procedures.

In first procedure `launch_workflow()` I assign a value to that variable. 
e.g. `l_emp_name:='Sanket Katariya';`

After that workflow launches.

in `approver_1 procedure` I get value of `l_emp_name` as `'sanket katariya'`, but in `apporver_2 procedure` I am getting a `null` value.

If I set `l_emp_name:='Sanket Katariya';` in `approver_1` again than I get its value in rest of procedure approver_2, approver_3,etc.

So logically that variable should be accessible in all procedures, right?

Please help me to understand this. Why do I need to set value to in `approver_1 procedure`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the code of package?
the **apporver_2** procedure is call in the same session as **approver_1** procedure?

Comment: PROCEDURE approve_1(ITEMTYPE IN VARCHAR2,ITEMKEY  IN VARCHAR2,ACTID IN NUMBER,FUNCMODE IN VARCHAR2,RESULT   IN OUT VARCHAR2) IS BEGIN
    l_emp_name := wf_engine.GetItemAttrText(itemtype => ITEMTYPE,itemkey  => ITEMKEY,aname    => 'INITIATOR');
mail_sub_atul_emp_no := 'Employee Master Registration Approval for Employee ' ||l_emp_name ||' to be approved by approver1';
    wf_engine.SetItemAttrText(itemtype => ITEMTYPE,itemkey  => ITEMKEY,aname    => 'EMAIL_SUBJECT_ATUL_EMP_NO',avalue   => mail_sub_atul_emp_no);
  END approve_1;

Comment: PROCEDURE approve_2(ITEMTYPE IN VARCHAR2,ITEMKEY  IN VARCHAR2,ACTID    IN NUMBER,FUNCMODE IN VARCHAR2,RESULT   IN OUT VARCHAR2) IS
 BEGIN
mail_sub_atul_emp_no := 'Employee Master Registration Approval for Employee ' ||l_emp_name ||' to be approved by IT Application Head';

wf_engine.SetItemAttrText(itemtype => ITEMTYPE,itemkey  => ITEMKEY,aname    => 'EMAIL_SUBJECT_ATUL_EMP_NO',avalue   => mail_sub_atul_emp_no);
END approve_2;